# how to mysql_real_escape_string SQL Query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

theres single quotes using in

```
$bio = "$user->description";
```

inserting DB like this;

```
<?
$sql = "insert into yyy (id, twitterid, twitterkullanici, tweetsayisi, takipettigi, takipeden, nerden, bio, profilresmi, ismi) values ('', '$id', '$twk', '$tws', '$tkpettigi', '$tkpeden', '$nerden', '$bio', '$img', '$isim')";

$ak = mysql_query("select * from yyy where twitterid = '$id'");
if (mysql_num_rows($ak) == 0) {
    $sonuc = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "ciciş listesine eklendin :)"; 
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($ak) == 1) {
    $sonuc = "zaten ciciş olarak eklenmişsin. ikinci kere eklemeye ne gerek var :)";
}

?>
```

how can i mysql_real_escape_string the $bio correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you establish a connection to your MySQL database first.

```
$sql = "insert into yyy (id, twitterid, twitterkullanici, tweetsayisi, takipettigi, takipeden, nerden, bio, profilresmi, ismi) values ('', '$id', '$twk', '$tws', '$tkpettigi', '$tkpeden', '$nerden', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($bio) . "', '$img', '$isim')";
```

FYI, this could have easily been found with a Google search or using the [PHP documention](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Also, you should use this for any strings and/or user submitted data. Not just select fields.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.
Start using parameterized queries with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or better, [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Example from the php doc with PDO :

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you -1 such a beautiful advice? Idiots. +1 from me dude.

Comment: Thanks Flavius. But I guess my tone is a little rude. I just hope the mysql extension is dropped in PhP 6.